# Function that accepts both &Vec<T> and &Vec<&T> in Rust

Tags: generics, rust

In my struct I have a `from` function that takes a shared reference to a vector of elements of type `T` and does some initialisation.

```
fn from(t: &Vec<T>) -> () {
    // ...
    for a in t {
        // ...
    }
    for a in t {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I also have another function `from_partial` that first performs some filtering on `&Vec<T>` and wants to pass this reduced list of elements to `from`. I don't want to clone so `from_partial` constructs the vector as `Vec<&T>` instead of `Vec<T>`. I also don't want to duplicate the logic in `from` as all in needs to do is loop over the vector and get a `&T` to store somewhere.

In my concrete type example, I can assign both `&Vec<&Bar>` and `&Vec<Bar>` to `from`

```
let a: &Vec<&Bar> = &test.iter().collect();
let b: &Vec<Bar> = test;
Foo::from(a); // can assign &Vec<&Bar>
Foo::from(b); // can assign &Vec<Bar>
```

However when working with generic types, I am unable to do so:

```
fn from_partial(t: &Vec<T>) -> () {
    // Here a function is called that does some filtering on &Vec<T>
    // and returns &Vec<&T>, but omitting for brevity.
    let example: &Vec<&T> = &t.iter().collect();
    Self::from(example); // cannot assign &Vec<&T> to &Vec<T>?
}
```

Here's the MVCE ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=208a748cd6994c01f22edaec35a00eb0)):

```
struct Foo<T> {
    t: T,
}
struct Bar {}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn from(t: &Vec<T>) -> () {
        let mut v = Vec::new();
        for a in t {
            // ...
            v.push(Foo { t: a })
        }
        for a in t {
            // ...
            v.get(0);
        }
    }

    fn from_partial(t: &Vec<T>) -> () {
        // Here a function is called that does some filtering on &Vec<T>
        // and returns &Vec<&T>, but omitting for brevity.
        let example: &Vec<&T> = &t.iter().collect();
        Self::from(example); // cannot assign &Vec<&T> to &Vec<T>?
    }
}

fn main() {}

fn test(test: &Vec<Bar>) {
    let a: &Vec<&Bar> = &test.iter().collect();
    let b: &Vec<Bar> = test;
    Foo::from(a); // can assign &Vec<&Bar>
    Foo::from(b); // can assign &Vec<Bar>
}
```

Is there any sort of constraint I can add on `T` that would make this possible? To essentially prevent me from duplicating exactly the same logic in `from` twice.

Comment: Related Q&A: [How to write a function that accepts a `Vec` of borrowed or owned elements?](/q/73839107/2189130) which answers the title more directly since he issue here was a simple misapplication of generic types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to replace `Self::from(example);` with `Foo::from(example);`.

Consider that `T` is `Bar`, then your `from_partial` call takes `&Vec<Bar>`. The issue is that `Self` then represents `Foo::<Bar>`, but you're trying to call `from` with `&Bar`, i.e. you need `Foo::<&Bar>`.

```rust
fn from_partial(t: &Vec<T>) -> () {
    let example: &Vec<&T> = &t.iter().collect();
    Foo::from(example);
}
```